# iOS animation flip book cover and ease up

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uianimation

I have a scroll view, and few buttons/images there. on clicking I would like such animation :

(image opens like )book cover opens, and related view controller opens with ease in animation and gets full screen.

Any thoughts ?

Something similar happening in cook app
Link of cook app : https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cook/id687560846?mt=8

Edit : I have added animation, gif will run uninterrupted once completely loaded.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried out like this :http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/

Comment: You may be interesting in http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-3d-page-folding-animation-page-sketch-spine-fold-effect--mobile-13473
It seems to have good explanation on how to do it, and adapt it to your wanted effect.

Answer (score 2):

Might I suggest [iBooksOpen](https://github.com/GuoLuchuan/iBooksOpen), a library that provides a book opening animation. It's pretty lightweight and should meet your needs.

(Only drawback: it opens a single page to the whole screen, but you could adapt the geometry if you wanted a page-folding-open effect.)